# PHP String for Specific css class

Tags: php

I found some css animation that I really liked on another site found here: http://cfbattorneys.com/

I am building it at: http://s2eg9.hosts.cx/

I am using the divi theme and put a code module to insert custom html and applied the css to the site and dropped in this code:

```
<a href="/criminal">
 <div class="home-service-box"> 
  <div class="outside-box"> 
   <div class="outer-border"> 
    <div class="inner-border"> 
     <div class="img-holder"> 
      <img src="http://glaszlaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Criminal.png"> 
     </div> 
    </div> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
 </div>
</a>
```

I was wondering if there was a way to put this html in a PHP string (I have very little experience with PHP) and call to it if I drop in a image module rather than a code module and give that image module a certain class or id? That way, when I’m editing in the backend of wordpress, if I wanted to swap out the image I could do so via the image module instead of seeing all this code and replacing the url string. If you look further down, you’ll see I have the same CSS animation on the team member photo as well.

Here is the css I used:

```
.home-service-box{
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 19.2%
} 

.outside-box {
  display: inline-block;
} 

.outer-border {
 display: block;
 border: 2px solid white;
 border-left: 2px solid transparent;
 margin: 30px; transition: .6s ease;
 border-radius: 50%;
 transform: rotate(-30deg);
} 

.inner-border {
 display: block;
 border: 2px solid white;
 border-right: 2px solid transparent;
 margin: 7px;
 transition: .6s ease;
 border-radius: 50%;
} 

.img-holder {
 display: block;
 margin: 15px;
 width: 55px;
 height: 55px;
 transition: .6s ease;
 background:transparent;
 transform: rotate(30deg);
} 

.img-holder>img {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 width:55px;
 height: 55px;
} 

.outside-box:hover .outer-border {
 border: 2px solid #d7a110;
 border-left: 2px solid transparent;
 transform: rotate(-210deg);
 transition: .6s ease;
} 

.outside-box:hover .inner-border{
 transform: rotate(360deg);
 border: 2px solid #d7a110;
 border-right: 2px solid transparent;
 transition: .6s ease;
} 

.outside-box:hover .img-holder{
 transform: rotate(-150deg);
 transition: .6s ease;
}

.team-img img{
 border-radius:50%;
} 

.team-img{
 display: block;
 margin: 15px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 transition: .6s ease;
 background:transparent;
 transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.team-img>img {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 width:200px;
 height: 200px;
}

.outside-box:hover .team-img{
 transform: rotate(-150deg);
 transition: .6s ease;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to rip off someone's code, at least do it *quietly*. Advertising that you're shamelessly stealing it is really brazen.

Comment: The CSS doesn't seem relevant to this question. Are you asking how you can use PHP to make modular templates?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the html area around:

```
<a class="banner-cta-btn" href="/index.php/our-firm/">
    meet your team
    <span class="btn-border vert left"></span>
    <span class="btn-border vert right"></span>
    <span class="btn-border hor top"></span>
    <span class="btn-border hor bottom"></span>
</a>
```

… and the associated css.

And yes, you should cite the original source, if in any way possible. Someone had to do the hard work.